# Randomize a std::list<std::string>

Tags: c++, list

So, I have an `std::list<std::string>` and I'm asking if there is  a function or a trick to randomize the list.

Example:

```
first elem of the list : "Hello"
second elem of the list : "Stack"
third elem of the list : "Over"
fourth elem of the list : "Flow"
fifth elem of the list : "!!"
```

what I want is  a function or a trick to get a random list like this for example :

```
first elem of the list : "Flow"
second elem of the list : "!!"
third elem of the list : "Hello"
fourth elem of the list : "Stack"
fifth elem of the list : "Over"
```

I think that You understand what I mean :)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Won't work on `std::list`. But then again, why is the OP using a list instead of a vector?

Comment: Specifically, `random()` or `random_shuffle()` won't work on a container that doesn't provide random access iterators.  And as mentioned, `std::list` is a **very unusual** container choice.  Almost always.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah, that's a very good point (wasn't that clear before 1st edit of the question). Why isn't a `std::vector<std::string>` used in 1st place?

Comment: i have used a list cause i need to remove from the middle of it and keeping the data sorted after randomizing the list

Comment: "Keeping the data sorted after randomizing the list" huh?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I wouldn't recommend `std::random_shuffle` - it's deprecated and C++17 will remove it. Just use `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @kfsone yes i want to randomize the list then in the middle of the program i want to delete from the middle of the list this way i have used lists instead of vectors cause vectors just have pop_back()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to keep your `list` as a list and even not modify it, but just provide a randomized "view" of it, then you can use a `vector<reference_wrapper<const string>>` and then shuffle the vector. This leaves the list intact, lets you see a shuffled version of it in the vector and doesn't need to copy all the strings.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::list<std::string> l{"Hello", "Stack", "Over", "flow", "!!"};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const std::string>> v(l.cbegin(), l.cend());
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), generator);
    std::cout << "Original list:\n";
    std::copy(l.cbegin(), l.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\nShuffled view:\n";
    std::copy(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Example output:

```
Original list:
Hello Stack Over flow !! 
Shuffled view:
Hello Over !! Stack flow
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/a1LIyh

Answer (score 1):

As people have mentioned, using a `std::list` in this circumstance is rather odd – really, you should be using something like `std::vector`, that will almost always do the same job better.

Nevertheless, for your case, the simplest 'non-solution' is to copy the list into a `std::vector`, use `std::random_shuffle`, and then copy it back again:

```
// get some data
std::list<std::string> data = getData();

// copy it into a vector and shuffle it
std::vector<std::string> temp(data.begin(), data.end());
std::random_shuffle(temp.begin(), temp.end());

// copy the (shuffled) vector back into the list
std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), data.begin());
```

Admittedly, it isn't all that efficient due to copying the entire set of data in both directions, but for your purpose it should be fine. If you wanted, you might be able to make it more efficient by moving the data  rather than using the `std::vector` constructor and `std::copy`, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Please don't use random_shuffle anymore. It is deprecated and will be removed in c++17. Use std::shuffle instead.

Comment: There's no need to copy. Just use `std::reference_wrapper` - see my answer.